# Euler formula for average derivative

Tags: calculus

From this [lecture](http://ecee.colorado.edu/copec/book/slides/Ch7slide.pdf) (page 22), there is a definion of average derivative as follows:

[Euler formula for derivative](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYvNY.png)

Could you explain where is the Euler formula here? I tried to search a lot but found nowhere talking about Euler formula relating to derivative.

Comment: Correct the title to euler

Comment: I think instead of "Euler formula" you want to search for "Euler method"  It is a way of approximating solutions to differential equations.  Essentially what your formula does is make a linear approximation of the derivative over a small time step.

Answer (score 1):

The Euler formula mentioned in the lecture is given as a method for derivative approximation, also called finite *forward-differences* approximation ([wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference)): here, you want to obtain a derivative w.r.t. $t$ which depend on the switching period $T_s$. The derivative definition says that
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}i(t)}{\mathrm{d}t} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{i(t+h) - i(t)}{h};
$$
we truncate some higher order infinitesimal terms by using
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}i(t)|_{T_s}}{\mathrm{d}t} = \frac{i(t + T_s) - i(t)}{T_s}.
$$

Can you see analogies and *differences*?